# Calculating $E[(X+Y)^2]$ where $X$ and $Y$ are dependent Bernouli RVs.

Tags: probability, expectation

Given:  P(X) = 1/4, P(Y) = 1/3, P(XY) = 1/8 (so not independent since P(XY) does not equal P(X)*P(Y)

Since these are Bernoulli RVs, we also have 
E(X) = 1/4, E(X^2) = 1/4, E(Y) = 1/3, E(Y^2) = 1/3, and E(XY) = 1/8

Trying to reconcile different ways to calculate E[(X+Y)^2]...simplest way which I believe yields the correct answer is:

E[(X+Y)^2] = E(X^2) + E(Y^2) + 2*E(XY) = 1/4 + 1/3 + 2*(1/4) = 5/6

However, if I use a "cases" approach I get a different answer:

Case 1:  Neither event X or Y occurs
Case 2:  Event X occurs, event Y does not occur
Case 3:  Event X does not occur, event Y occurs
Case 4:  Both events X and Y occur

E[(X+Y)^2] = P(Case 1)*(0+0)^2 + P(Case 2)*(1+0)^2 + P(Case 3)*(0+1)^2 + P(Case 4)*(1+1)^2 = 3/4(2/3)*0 + 1/4(2/3)(1) + 3/4(1/3)(1) + 1/8(4) = 11/12

I am guessing that the cases approach is not valid here, but I can't explain to myself exactly why....I do note that the Cov(X,Y) can be easily calculated as 1/24, and if I subtract out 2*Cov(X,Y) = 1/12 I get the original answer of 5/6 but I am having trouble connecting the dots here as to why this needs to be done...

Or does the trouble lie perhaps in my assumption that E(XY) = P(XY)?   I have trouble seeing how that could be incorrect though....

Comment: As you said: not independent. But you seem to use the non-existant independency by computing the $P(\text{case }i)$ for $i=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: "I am guessing that the cases approach is not valid here, but I can't explain to myself exactly why..." Because you don't know P(X=0,Y=0), as this is different from P(X=0)P(Y=0) (what you did calculate)

Comment: Ok yes, the probabilities for the cases are wrong, since just as P(XY) does not equal P(X)*P(Y) due to dependence, P(XY') does not equal P(X)*P(Y'), etc...

Answer (score 1):

Second method work fine:

\begin{eqnarray*}
E((X+Y)^2) &=& 1\cdot P(X\cap\neg Y) + 1\cdot P(\neg X\cap Y) + 4\cdot P(X\cap Y) \\
&=& [P(X)-P(X\cap Y)] + [P(Y) - P(X\cap Y)] + 4\cdot P(X\cap Y) \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{8} + \dfrac{5}{24} + 4\cdot \dfrac{1}{8} \\
&=& \dfrac{5}{6}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks, feeling a bit silly after thinking more about my own question.  Simple Venn Diagram would have lead me to Mick A's answer for the cases approach... thanks to all contributors/commenters

Comment: @user221943 Glad to help.